# Cannot access a disposed object Error when Call component two times in a row

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, components, dispose

In my project I have a component that displays a list of products in a specific group.

```
public class ProductListIncategoryViewComponent : ViewComponent
    {
        private IProductRepository productRepository;

        public ProductListIncategoryViewComponent(IProductRepository repoprod)
        {
            productRepository = repoprod;

        }
        public IViewComponentResult Invoke(int priorityid)
        {

            MixProductView result = productRepository.SelectByCategory(priorityid);
            return View(result);

        }
    }
```

Component input is groupID.

So I call the component twice to show the products of the two groups. for example:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductListIncategory", new { priorityid = 3 })
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductListIncategory", new { priorityid = 4 }) //Error
```

I have an error when doing it two times in a row.

> Cannot access a disposed object. A common cause of this error is
>   disposing a context that was resolved from dependency injection and
>   then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your
>   application. This may occur if you are calling Dispose() on the
>   context, or wrapping the context in a using statement. If you are
>   using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection
>   container take care of disposing context instances. Object name:
>   'KuteCoredbContext

but There is no Erro when calling the component once

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductListIncategory", new { priorityid = 3 })
```

or when call component by other groupid

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("ProductListIncategory", new { priorityid = 4 })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

I needed to add this command  to startup.cs after `services.AddDbContext`

```
services.AddDbContext<KuteCoredbContext>(option => option.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:KuteCore:ConnectionString"]));
services.AddTransient<KuteCoredbContext>();// <----add thos command
```